# Load true color image into CImage

Tags: image, mfc

How can I load jpeg file into CImage in true color? When I load it and then save to disk it's written correctly saving old palette, but if i draw it on form it's drawn in poor 256-like color.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is with the image you load, but with the CDC that you are drawing into. Make sure the CDC supports true color.